# Power BIs Map with Danish post codes

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to add data to a Map with Danish postcodes, e.g. 1000-9000 (we have four digits in Denmark).

When I add that into a Map, it scatters all over the world, as Power BI do not recognize it as Danish locations, even my Power BI is setup in Danish and the Map has Danish spelled city names.

I tried to add the regions Jylland, Fyn, Sjælland as a country hierarchy, but doing that moved Jylland (Jutland) as a place in Norway...

I also tried to use city names instead of post codes, but then a city shows up in Sweden...

It does not change whether the post code format is Text or Number format, and I have no option to use a Location format in the query.

Can anyone help me use Danish post codes for Map visualization? : )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it myself!

I found the place in the modelling part where I could force PowerBI to accept my city names, region names etc. and it now works.

More detailed: go into the middle of the three left side windows called Data (not Report, not Model), and click on the column you want to change format of. Then find the Tools section and change the Data Category to for example Address, or Country etc. Hope that helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).